# Show that ${(1,0,0),(2,1,0),(3,2,1),(4,3,2)}$ is a frame for $H=R^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, harmonic-analysis

Show that ${(1,0,0),(2,1,0),(3,2,1),(4,3,2)}$ is a frame for $H=R^3$.
I'm confused on how to show it, please help me

[Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lyxl.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have the definition of a frame? What part of the definition is confusing?

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve the problem from the definition I provided

Comment: @mikethird Can you prove the collection is countable? Do you know how to calculate the inner product given in the definition? If so, which constant is giving you trouble, $A$ or $B$?